# C++ class instantiate as method argument

Tags: c++, arguments, constants, inline

Quick question, (C++)

Say I have a function called `findPlayer( Player &p )`

If I call that as follows

```
findPlayer(Player());
```

what is the const-ness of local `p` inside `findPlayer`?

In addition, is `Player()` passed by reference or value? I'm guessing value...

Comment: `findPlayer(Player())` shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @Mankarse It shouldn't, but if I recall correctly, allowing temporaries for non-const references is one of the more prominent areas of non-conformance of one major C++ compiler.

Comment: @hvd: That may be true, but without mention of that, this question is fairly meaningless.

Comment: @Mankarse I'm only pointing it out because the OP may not realise it is invalid, because there is a fair chance the OP did try to compile it, and got no indication whatsoever that anything was wrong.

Comment: @Mankarse thanks for the feedback. I did compile and it hadn't complained specifically about that, however I'm in the process of overhauling a lot of code so it's not in a stable build at the moment. I will take this into consideration and see how it works moving forward. An interesting matter to note is that I've accomplished something similar with other objects throughout the code and it hasn't complained once.

Comment: @Volte: I'm assuming you are using MSVC, in which case I would suggest activating the [/Za](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) switch to disable the C++ incompatible extensions supplied by that compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the fact that

```
findPlayer(Player());
```

shouldn't compile, the behavior of a `p` in `findPlayer()` is not dependent on how it gets called. That would defeat the purpose of the function's interface.

When you have a function whose interface is `findPlayer(Player& p)`, you are telling the world that `findPlayer` can access anything from `p` that are available through the public interface of `Player` on on-const objects.

Comment: True, I guess what I mean't was what is the const-ness of a temporary object. (Didn't have the language to describe that until now)

Comment: @Volte Take a look at this [SO post on the subect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object). Hopefully things will make more sense after reading it.

Answer (score 0):

`findPlayer( Player &p )` with `findPlayer(Player())` should give error indicating constant-ness, the function should be defined as `findPlayer(const Player &p )` , and a constant reference will be useless except using a pass-by-reference approach for that method.